# How can I obtain raw data from a CVImageBuffer object

Tags: cocoa, macos, webcam, qtkit

I'm trying to use cocoa to grab images from a webcam. I'm able to get the image in RGBA format using the QTKit and the didOutputVideoFrame delegate call, and converting the CVImageBuffer to a CIImage and then to a NSBitmapImageRep.

I know my camera grabs natively in YUV, what I want is to get the YUV data directly from the CVImageBuffer, and proccess the YUV frame before displaying it.

My question is: How can I get the YUV data from the CVImageBuffer?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to create a `CIImage` from the buffer using `+[CIImage imageWithCVBuffer:]` and then render that CIImage into a `CGBitmapContext` of the desired pixel format.

Note, I have not tested this solution.

Comment: CIImage can grab the CVBuffer directly. Doesn't even require locking the base address

Comment: @Barry Wark any advice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611593/how-to-create-cvpixelbufferref-with-nv12-data

Answer (score 1):

I asked what I thought was a different question, but it turned out to have the same answer as this one: [raw data from CVImageBuffer without rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626703/raw-data-from-cvimagebuffer-without-rendering/5630737#5630737)