# How to convert a CVImageBufferRef to an OpenGL texture

Tags: objective-c, image, opengl, textures

I need to create an OpenGL texture of type GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, so that I can use

```
outputImageProviderFromTextureWithPixelFormat:pixelsWide:pixelsHigh:name:flipped:releaseCallback:releaseContext:colorSpace:shouldColorMatch
```

, but I can't figure out how to convert my CVImageBufferRef to an OpenGL texture.  I'm sure I'm just no looking for the right thing.  How can I convert an CVImageBufferRef to an OpenGL texture?

When I try:

```
   CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CVBufferRetain(mCurrentImageBuffer);

    GLuint                  texture = CVOpenGLTextureGetName(imageBuffer);


    id provider= [context outputImageProviderFromTextureWithPixelFormat:QCPlugInPixelFormatARGB8
                                                             pixelsWide:CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
                                                             pixelsHigh:CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)
                                                                   name:texture
                                                                flipped:NO
                                                        releaseCallback:_TextureReleaseCallback
                                                         releaseContext:NULL
                                                             colorSpace:CVImageBufferGetColorSpace(imageBuffer)
                                                       shouldColorMatch:YES];
```

It tells me that 'name' cannot be null.  I think that's because my imageBuffer is a pixel buffer, and not an OpenGL Texture.  How can I create a OpenGL texture from my pixel buffer ?

Answer (score 1):

There might be some special fast-path in the CoreVideo framework, but you could always get the raw backing data and supply it to `glTexImage2D`.  Here's an [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626703/raw-data-from-cvimagebuffer-without-rendering) which covers getting the raw data.

*Edit:*

Digging a little more, it seems you might be able to simply use the OpenGL texture already associated with your `CVImageBufferRef` by using `CVOpenGLTextureGetTarget` and `CVOpenGLTextureGetName`.  These operate on `CVOpenGLTextureRef` types, which is typedef'd to `CVImageBufferRef`.

Comment: I tried using CVOpenGLTextureGetName(imageBuffer),and it seems to return null.  I got '2011-11-20 12:23:52.607 Quartz Composer[18612:407] *** EXCEPTION IGNORED: -[CaptureWithDevice outputImageProviderFromTextureWithPixelFormat:pixelsWide:pixelsHigh:name:flipped:releaseCallback:releaseContext:colorSpace:shouldColorMatch:]: Argument "name" cannot be null' when I ran it..

Comment: After reading the other thread you mentioned, I think the reason it's  returning null is because my imageBuffer isn't an OpenGL buffer.  So, still, I need to convert from a pixel buffer an open GL texture.

Comment: Ah, I see.  You could try the raw-data route, then.  Unfortunately, I have't done a lot of work with CoreVideo.